# Function to calculate all combinations

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to write a function which loops through a data set and returns the maximum value of a given path through the data.

I have an array of arrays. Each array has a number of objects(not always the same) and each object has a `name` and a `probability` property.

```
[
[{name: AAA, probability: .7}, {name:BBB, probability: .6}, {name: CCC, probability: .1}],
[{name: AAA, probability: .8}, {name: CCC, probability: .7}, {name: DDD, probability: .4}],
[{name: AAA, probability: .8}, {name: BBB, probability: .5}, {name: DDD, probability: .8}]
]
```

Above is a simplified example of my dataset. I want to find the maximum probability by combining one object from each array. Once a particular object is chosen an object with the same name cannot be chosen again.

In other words I want to find the maximum value of `probability from array 1` multiplied by `probability from array 2` multiplied by `probability from array 3` without any repeats to `name`.

I am not sure if there is a clever math trick to solve this without trying all combos (please let me know if there is), but for now I just want to brute force the solution.

I could solve this by nesting a for loop for each array in my data set but this would grow needlessly large.

```
const selection=[]
for(array of data){
 for(object of array){
  if(selction.includes(object.name)){
    selction.push(object.name)
    for(object + 1 of array){
      ...
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Basically i want to avoid writing out a for loop for every single array in my data set.

If the problem is still confusing I can add more detail.

Comment: *"I want to find the maximum probability"* - you want to find the item with the greatest `probability` property?

Comment: so the expected result of your example will be `0.7 * 0.7 * 0.8`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that is correct.  Basically I need to test for all combinations without repeating a name.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array (with [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through each item to extract the `probability` properties, then use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to get the largest item in the resulting array:

```js
const arr = [
  [{name: 'AAA', probability: .7}, {name:'BBB', probability: .6}, {name: 'CCC', probability: .1}],
  [{name: 'AAA', probability: .8}, {name: 'CCC', probability: .7}, {name: 'DDD', probability: .4}],
  [{name: 'AAA', probability: .8}, {name:'BBB', probability: .5}, {name: 'DDD', probability: .8}]
]

const highestProbability = Math.max(...arr.flat().map(e => e.probability))

console.log(highestProbability)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just give my the highest probability of each array?

Comment: @tdammon It would give the highest of all the arrays, since the original array was flattened.

Comment: I edited my post for clarity.  I am looking for a maximum value of the product of multiplying one probability from every array.

Comment: This won't work. The author stated that you can't use a property with the same name.